# Adicionar ícones/imagens em tags

Tags: novo-recurso, tags

É possível que nós possamos adicionar ícones/imagens nas tags assim como algumas tags no *Stack Overflow em inglês*?

Por exemplo a do *Firefox*, *Android* e do *Internet Explorer*:

[image: icones em tags stackexchange]

Ou apenas os administradores podem fazer isto? Acham que seria interessante para nós que alguém adicione ícones do tipo?

Comment: Basta eles pagarem que a SE coloca :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Que eu saiba, no Stack Overflow em inglês as tags com ícones são patrocinadas, ou seja, Google, Mozilla, Microsoft e outros **pagam** à Stack Exchange para ter esse tipo de destaque em tags que correspondem aos seus produtos.

Provavelmente o acordo não inclui as tags do SOpt, o que faz sentido comercialmente. Para colocar os ícones também aqui, eles provavelmente terão de pagar mais.

Comment: Está aí uma informação que eu não fazia ideia.

Comment: Ou pagar menos, já que a empresa pode alcançar o publico exclusivo do idioma PT :)

Comment: Faço das palavras do @Math as minhas :) acho que poucos tinham ideia sobre isto. Obrigado +1